# Why i can't test my versionist route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have versioned route like this

```
api_version(:module => "api/v1", :path => "api/v1") do
  match '/files' => 'files#index', :via => :get
end
```

And my controller app/controllers/api/v1/files_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::FilesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

end
```

spec in root/spec/controllers/api/v1/files_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V1::FilesController do

  describe "routing" do

    it "should routes to version-1 api" do
      expect(:get => "/api/v1/files").to route_to("api/v1/files#index")
    end

  end

end
```

command rake routes gives me a list of my routes like this

```
devise/registrations#edit
                          PUT    /users(.:format)  devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)  devise/registrations#destroy
             api_v1_files GET    /api/v1/files(.:format)      api/v1/files#index
```

when i run rake spec:controllers, specs falls.

```
F

Failures:

1) Api::V1::FilesController routing should routes to version-1 api
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 # /home/dilshod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/moped-1.2.7/lib/moped/node.rb:74:in `block in command'
 # /home/dilshod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/moped-1.2.7/lib/moped/n
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solve problem with update RUBY to 1.9.3